# Checkbox overflows in Chrome on Retina screen

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, overflow

A very interesting problem I came across today, maybe you can think of something. Bear with me, it is very complicated and probably a bug in Chrome :D To be exact, this is needed to reproduce the issue:

- A HiDPI screen (I tested it on a Retina MacBook)
- Chrome 40 (My client had the problem with v39 though, but I didn't test that)

Update: I tested this on an iPad and on Safari for Mac (because they both use Webkit and have a HiDPI screen), no problem. It seems to be limited to Chrome.

- An element on the page with a `transform` property
- *After* that (anywhere, not directly after it), a div with the following specifics:

  - A `border-radius`
  - `overflow: scroll/auto` and a fixed (or max-) height
  - Containing checkboxes that are `position: relative`

This will break the checkboxes, which will be still visible even though there is an `overflow: scroll`. Any other elements (text) will be hidden properly, and it only happens for checkboxes, no other inputs.

Sample code:

```
<div class="bug"></div>
<div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <br>
</div>

.bug {
    transform: translateZ(0px);
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: relative;
}
.container {
    /* Needed */
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    border-radius: 2px;

    /* Illustration purposes */
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

JSFiddle (already scrolled a bit so you can immediately see the problem): http://jsfiddle.net/b4LtsbLv/

Screen should you not have access to HiDPI displays:

[image]

Any ideas or should I file this as a bug in Chrome? Btw, in real life this happens on a page with a Google map that has also a scrollable list with Checkboxes :)

Comment: Those inputs need labels. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Answer (score 0):

Just getting rid of the border-radius on the container seems to fix it. Do you need that for some reason?

```
.container {
    /* Needed */
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    /*border-radius: 2px;*/
    /* Illustration purposes */
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b4LtsbLv/3/

Comment: I know, that would be a workaround. I would be more interested why that happens :D

Comment: That was what I also suspected, yes.